# In Tailwind CSS, justify-self-end doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind CSS and I have a problem with `justify-self-end`. It works in Chrome, but not in Firefox. I have uploaded two pictures so to understand better what's happening. Is there something I can do to make it work in both browsers?

```
<section class="lg:grid lg:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-rows-1 lg:h-screen overflow-hidden">
  <div class="justify-self-end bg-[#2e3362] px-[1em] lg:px-[0] mb-[1.875em] lg:mb-0">
    <img
      src="../img/alarm.webp"
      class="alarm cursor-pointer shadow-lg rounded-[1em] lg:rounded-l-full max-w-full h-[90%]"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="bg-[#2e3362] px-[1em] lg:px-[0] mb-[1.875em] lg:mb-0">
    <img
      src="../img/camera.webp"
      class="camera cursor-pointer shadow-lg rounded-[1em] lg:rounded-r-full max-w-full h-[90%]"
    />
  </div>
</section>
```

**Firefox**
[image: this happens with firefox]

**Chrome**
[image: this happens with chrome]

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you:

```
<section class="lg:grid lg:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-rows-1 lg:h-screen overflow-hidden">
  <div class="flex justify-end bg-[#2e3362] px-[1em] lg:px-[0] mb-[1.875em] lg:mb-0">
    <img
      src="../img/alarm.webp"
      class="alarm cursor-pointer shadow-lg rounded-[1em] lg:rounded-l-full max-w-full h-[90%]"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="bg-[#2e3362] px-[1em] lg:px-[0] mb-[1.875em] lg:mb-0">
    <img
      src="../img/camera.webp"
      class="camera cursor-pointer shadow-lg rounded-[1em] lg:rounded-r-full max-w-full h-[90%]"
    />
  </div>
</section>
```

I added flex and justify-end to the first div.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It didn't change! But thank you for trying to help!

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I tried with tailwind playground and a couple of stock images and it worked in both Chrome and Firefox. 
I suggest you to paste my code in the playground (you will need to put random images in the route) and check if there is any difference in the behaviour. Maybe it gives you some clues on how to solve it